# Evaluate symfun at a symbolic variable instead of a number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode, mupad, dsolve, sym

I created a symbolic function in MATLAB R2021b using this script with the goal of solving an ODE.

```
syms phi(x) lambda L
eqn_x = diff(phi,x,2) == -lambda*phi;
dphi = diff(phi,x);
cond = [phi(0)==0, dphi(1)==0]; % this is the line where the problem starts
disp(cond)
```

[image: conditions_v1]

```
phi = dsolve(eqn_x,x,cond);
```

This script runs without any errors, but I want to evaluate `dphi(L)==0` instead of at x=1. When I try to do this instead, I get the following error.

[image: conditions_v2]

[image: error]

Obviously, the way MATLAB is interpreting `dphi(L)==0` is not correct since it is replacing the dependent parameter x with L which should be an independent parameter. Can someone recommend a fix or workaround?

I've also tried this `dphi(x==L)==0` and I got the same error.

[image: conditions_v3]

**Addition following kikon's comment**
I tried both options suggested based on the tutorial. These are the results.

1. `dphi | x = L` creates a parse error in MATLAB
2. `dphi | x == L` gives this result. *This seems to indicate x=l OR dphi/dx which is not a condition.* I'm tempted to try `&` in place of `|` to get an and, but this may not be sufficient.

[image: conditions_v5]

3. `subs(dphi, x = L)` gives the same condition when I use `dphi(L)==0` which is incorrect.

Comment: I don't have mupad installed but I used it a lot in the past and I suppose it should be one of `dphi | x = L` or `subs(dphi, x = L)`. Check page 171 in [this tutorial](https://sites.calvin.edu/tmk5/research/mupad_tutorial.pdf)

Comment: what is the line of code that errors?

Comment: @kikon I will check tutorial, thank you.

Comment: @AnderBiguri this is the line that causes the error, `phi = dsolve(eqn_x,x,cond);`

Comment: but what is `dphi(L)==0` then?

Comment: As I explained, MATLAB replaces the independent variable x with L instead of evaluating x at a value of L.